# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, curl, twilio

I typed this into terminal

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/voice
```

and I got this error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

I've looked everywhere for a solution I can understand, but found no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have a server running on that port? because that's the error you'll get if you don't

Comment: seems that nothing is running on that port or `localhost` is not in `hosts file`... try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: Try checking if anything's listening on port 3000. Run `lsof -iTCP -P -n`. There may be quite a few things with open connections, so piping it through `grep 3000` may help. If nothing shows up, make sure your server's running.

Comment: Hi, you should start local host with port 3000. if you are in node.js, you should type in command prompt. `npm start`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have not started your local host with port 3000.

Try http://localhost:3000/ in your browser. See if it's connected.

If not, you need to start your local host first with port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I think port `3000` is not open on the host. To see if something is listening on a certain port or open at all, you can use `netstat -tlpen | grep 8080` or `nc -vz [host] [port]`.

Answer (score 0):

it's needed to start the localhost with port 3000:
1-Run the server, if for example with a node server: `$ node nameOfCode.js`
2-then in a new terminal type `curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/voice`
i did it and it worked for me